# Can't get my code to return an object from my ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to get it so that when a user enters, for example, the model of a guitar that it will return all the details for that specific model from my `ArrayList`. However, I get no errors when I run the program just no results. I have no clue what to do, any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. In my switch cases I kept trying multiple different ways to get results with no luck so please ignore if it is all over the place.

```
package guitarsrentalmanagementsystem;

import StockManagement.Guitar;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuitarsRentalManagementSystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here        
        ArrayList<Guitar> data = new ArrayList<>();
        data.add(new Guitar(100, 150.99, "Gibson", "Les Paul", 
                "Acoustic", "INDIAN_ROSEWOOD", "MAHOGANY", 1995, 8.99,  "Red", 
        true));
        data.add(new Guitar(101, 180.00, "Fender", "Stratocaster", 
                "Electric", "BRAZILIAN_ROSEWOOD", "MAHOGANY", 2001, 10.99, "Brown", 
        true));
        data.add(new Guitar(102, 110.50, "Martin", "Noisemaker", 
                "Acoustic", "INDIAN_ROSEWOOD", "BRAZILIAN_ROSEWOOD", 2005, 5.99, "Black", 
        true));

        for(Guitar g : data){
            g.printDetail();
        }

        //Show data from the adobe arraylist        
        System.out.println("Valid search parameters are as follows :");
        System.out.println("1. Model, eg Les Paul");
        System.out.println("2. Serial number, eg 101");
        System.out.println("3. Year of manufacture, eg 2001");         

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please select how you would like to search");        
        int search = input.nextInt(); 
        for(Guitar g : data){
        switch(search){
            case 1:                
                System.out.println("You have chosen to search by model");
                System.out.println("Valid models are Les Paul, Stratocaster or Noisemaker");
                System.out.println("Please enter a model to search");                
                Scanner inputO1 = new Scanner(System.in);
                String modelSearch = input.next();
                if("Les Paul".equals(modelSearch)){
                    g.printDetail();
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("You have chosen to search by Serial number");
                System.out.println("valid serial numbers are between 100 and 105");
                System.out.println("Please enter a serial number to search");
                Scanner inputO2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                int serialSearch = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println(g.getSerialNumber());                
                break;

            case 3:                
                System.out.println("You have chosen to search by year of manufacture");    
                System.out.println("Valid manufacture dates are 1995, 2001 and 2005");
                System.out.println("Please enter a manufacture year to search");
                Scanner input03 = new Scanner(System.in);
                int yearSearch = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println(g.getYearOfManufacture());

                break;
        } 
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the break on line 79 doesn't look right

Comment: @AbdulAhad, I removed the line numbers to enable the formatter to do its work. The break you mean is the last one. I guess it was added to stop the `for` loop after the first element to allow easier debugging…

Answer (score 1):

There's issue with the way you are reading input: when you use scanner object and call nextInt() on it. it reads just the number. similarly when you call next it reads just one string value, i.e.

if you have entered "Les Paul" as input, scanner object next() method will ready only Les, so it wouldn't match with your condition.

so once you read integer call nextLine() method, so the cursor moves to next line, now read input from the next line by calling again the nextLine() method

```
 case 1:
   System.out.println("You have chosen to search by model");
   System.out.println("Valid models are Les Paul, Stratocaster or Noisemaker");
   System.out.println("Please enter a model to search");
   Scanner inputO1 = new Scanner(System.in);
   input.nextLine();
   String modelSearch = input.nextLine();
   if ("Les Paul".equals(modelSearch)) {
    g.printDetail();
   }
   break;
```

the above code will work if the user enters model as "Les Paul".